# .remove() not removing all the contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/mpqA7/2/) - where I make an image resizable and draggable in the Ready function. A droppable `div` is also created to accept the image's resizable `.ui-wrapper`, so the image can be dragged and dropped into the `div`. In the drop handler I want to remove the `ui.draggable` entirely from the droppable `div`, since something else will be put there.

I tried doing this with `remove()`:

```
ui.draggable.remove();
```

which should have removed the .ui-wrapper and everything inside, according to my reading of the jQuery reference. But it's only removing the outer ui-wrapper, and leaving the img element.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because draggable is an array. You can delete the first draggable like this:

```
ui.draggable[0].remove()
```

Comment: Actually, `[0]` will return the `div` element. Somehow it works though.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know the *why*, I'll look into the jQuery-UI core and update answer later, but I'm sure it has something to do with the order of the events firing

As as workaround you can do

```
var ele = e.toElement ? e.toElement : e.relatedTarget; 
$(ele).remove();
```

For the time being.

The ternary check is to support cross browser.